# How to count 0 to 10 with setInterval

Tags: jquery, html, count, setinterval

I wrote a simple code to count and display number that count in loop.

but it doesn't work. :(

pls show me my problem.

TnX

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){
            function myCount() {
                var count = 0;
                if (count == 0) {
                    count += 1;  
                } else if (count > 10) {
                    count = 0;
                }
                $('.count').text(count);
            }
            setInterval(myCount(),200);
        });        

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Count form 0 to 10: <span class="count"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *puts up fist, "Zero." Yup, it's at zero. Add one. Set back to zero. Yup, It's zero. Add one. Set back to zero. (repeats on for hours...)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments in code below and fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dRMrL/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // someone already explained why count has to be declared outside the function
    var count = 0;

    function myCount() {
        // your original if-else wasn't allowing count to increment past 1
        if (count > 10) {
            count = 0;
        }
        $('.count').text(count);
        // increment count regardless of its current value
        count++;
    }

    setInterval(myCount, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your variable `count` outside the function, otherwise you recreate the variable and will always be `0` when starting your function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;

    function myCount() {
        if (count == 0) {
            count += 1;
        } else if (count > 10) {
            count = 0;
        }
        $('.count').text(count);
    }
    setInterval(myCount, 200);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `count` to 0 each time you call the function, so declare count outside of the function's scope.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  var count = 0;
  function myCount() {
    if (count == 0) {
      count += 1;  
    } else if (count > 10) {
      count = 0;
    }
    $('.count').text(count);
  }
  setInterval(myCount,200);
});
```

Comment: `setInterval(myCount(),200);` should be `setInterval(myCount,200);`